# Mapping a list by a function, on click give me error: "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list that I'm trying to map by a function that isn't in react's `render()` function.
In this function there is a div which has an `onClick` attribute and the function which is assigned, but the whole stuff give me a `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` error.

There is the code:

```js
import React from 'react'; 

export default class Example{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            indexes: [
                {
                    title: "title1",
                    content: ["content", "content", "content"]
                },
                {
                    title: "title2",
                    content: ["content", "content", "content"]
                },
            ]
        };
    }

    example(){
        console.log("example");
    }

    indexRender({title, content}){
        return(
            <>
            {/* display title */}
            <div onClick={this.example}>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <img src="example.png" width={20} />
            </div>
            {/* display content */}
            <div>
                {content.map((cont) => {
                    return(
                        <a key={cont.id}>{cont}</a>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }

    render(){
        const indexes = this.state.indexes;

        return(
            <nav>
                {indexes.map(this.indexRender)}
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

EDIT
I forgot to write the function I would like to call in the code and the error occurs when rendering.

Comment: What/where is `this.openDropdown` callback function? Does the error occur when rendering, or later when trying to invoke the callback? More details please, and clear reproducible steps for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One:

You did not bind your object, you can use the arrow method to avoid object binding problem. I guess that could be the issue or one of the issues. You can bind it this way:

```
indexRender = ({title, content}) => {
        return(
            <div onClick={this.openDropdown}>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <img src="example.png" width={20} />
            </div>
            <div>
                {content.map((cont, i) => {
                    return(
                        <a key={i}>{cont}</a>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Two:

I know you're trying to use some abstraction here which is fine. But you can try this instead:

```
  render(){
      const indexes = this.state.indexes;

  return (
          <nav>

        {indexes.map(({title, content}) => {
          <>
            <div key={i} onClick={this.openDropdown}>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <img src="example.png" width={20} />
            </div>

            {/* display content */}
            <div>
                {content.map((cont, i) => {
                    return(
                        <a key={cont.id}>{cont}</a>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    })
 )
```

)

I hope this helps you out, if it doesn't, you can place in the code for your *this.openDropdown* method, let's see.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'll go with your solution. Just a quick question, is this a best practice or is it to create a function to pass as a param in map function (like I did in my question)?

Comment: Neither of them is wrong practices. It just depends on what you want to do and how you do it. I'm editing and adding more cases to do in a better way the way you did it in your question.

Comment: There, I've edited the answer and added something you missed. So both ways, your way and my way (Two:) are different ways of implementing class components.